# mailgun deliverytime not sending scheduled emails

Tags: python, python-2.7, mailgun

I am sending emails using Mailgun and am trying to delay the delivery but I am not getting the results that I was expecting, even with a 200 response. The emails just don't seem to be coming through.

Mailgun says that deliverytime dates need to be formatted as a string and encoded as RFC 2882.

I am trying to add time to the current time so that the email gets sent 30 seconds later. I have done this by importing...

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from email.utils import formatdate
```

and then by storing the time in a variable to be called in the function

```
time1 = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=30)
time1 = formatdate(float(time1.strftime('%s')))
```

I get a 200 status code that says the message has been queued but it never actually comes through. In the Mailgun logs the time comes through as a weird number like this...

```
"scheduled-for": 1491987288,
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Please help.

Comment: Why are you using float?

Comment: I got rid of float and formatdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to import strftime and move the time1 variable so that it was after my form.validate_on_submit() in Flask. stupid mistake.